# Uber API Usage acceptability

Tags: uber-api

I was planning to use Uber API's in conjunction with other providers to display the results together. Is it allowed by Uber?

I saw in the Uber FAQ that these API's cannot be used for comparisons. But need to understand this for sure

Regards,
Amit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not allowed by the terms of conditions to build comparison applications.

Comment: So it means if you put in the pickup and drop locations and you show list of all taxi's available from Uber and others with the time to arrive and price, it is not allowed?